# D3.js: Is there a was to delete annotations in a pie chart when switching the dataset?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I've been working on a school project that's due tomorrow, and we have to make a data visualisation using the d3 chart library. I've found some code that allows me to add annotations to my pie chart, but I don't know how to delete the previous annotations when switching datasets. Can anyone help me out?

**HTML code:**

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var width = 450
    height = 450
    margin = 40

// The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

// append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// create  data_set
var data1 = {a: 1, b: 20, c:30, d:20, e:20}
var data2 = {a: 6, b: 16, c:20, d:14, e:19, f:12}
var data3 = {a: 9, b: 1}
var data4 = {a: 1, b: 2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6}
var data5 = {a: 2, b: 3, c:4, d:1, e:8}
var data6 = {a: 3, b: 9, c:5, d:3, e:2, f:3}

// set the color scale
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
  .range(d3.schemeDark2);

// A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
function update(data) {

  // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
  var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) {return d.value; })
    .sort(function(a, b) { console.log(a) ; return d3.ascending(a.key, b.key);} ) // This make sure that group order remains the same in the pie chart
  var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))


  // The arc generator
  var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.5)         // This is the size of the donut hole
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)


  // Another arc that won't be drawn. Just for labels positioning
  var outerArc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.9)

  
  // map to data
  var u = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data_ready)

  // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
  u
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .merge(u)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('d', d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(0)
      .outerRadius(radius)
    )
    .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .style("stroke-width", "2px")
    .style("opacity", 1)

  // Add the polylines between chart and labels:
  svg
    .selectAll('allPolylines')
    .data(data_ready)
    .enter()
    .append('polyline')
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr('points', function(d) {
        var posA = arc.centroid(d) // line insertion in the slice
        var posB = outerArc.centroid(d) // line break: we use the other arc generator that has been built only for that
        var posC = outerArc.centroid(d); // Label position = almost the same as posB
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2 // we need the angle to see if the X position will be at the extreme right or extreme left
        posC[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1); // multiply by 1 or -1 to put it on the right or on the left
        return [posA, posB, posC]
      })

  // Add the polylines between chart and labels:
  svg
    .selectAll('allLabels')
    .data(data_ready)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
      .text( function(d) { console.log(d.data.key) ; return d.data.key } )
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
          var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
          var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
          pos[0] = radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
          return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
      })
      .style('text-anchor', function(d) {
          var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
          return (midangle < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end')
      })  
  
  
  // remove the group that is not present anymore
  u
    .exit()
    .remove()
  
}

// Initialize the plot with the first dataset
update(data1)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Color scale -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add buttons -->
<button onclick="update(data1)">Data 1</button>
<button onclick="update(data2)">Data 2</button>
<button onclick="update(data3)">Data 3</button>
<button onclick="update(data4)">Data 4</button>
<button onclick="update(data5)">Data 5</button>
<button onclick="update(data6)">Data 6</button>


  <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
</head>

<body>
  Lorem Ipsum
  <script src="script.js"></script>

 <!--
  This script places a badge on your repl's full-browser view back to your repl's cover
  page. Try various colors for the theme: dark, light, red, orange, yellow, lime, green,
  teal, blue, blurple, magenta, pink!
  -->
  <script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge.js" theme="blue" defer></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried using the .exit() and .remove() functions, but I think that I've missed these functions, as they have not been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Before you add the polylines add

```
svg.selectAll("polyline").remove();
```

And before you do labels add

```
svg.selectAll("text").remove();
```

Good luck on project!

Comment: This worked for me, thank you very much!

Comment: Pleasure. Do note that you have other errors in console and several other things wrong with HTML. for instance you have 3 doctype declarations.<!DOCTYPE html> and buttons are in head tag not body. Suggest you get a good editor and take advantage of services like https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea